# Login function using phpmyadmin and SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

So i've made this login function using PHP and im having trouble asking a question correctly to the phpmyadmin database, basically the question i ask now is "SELECT * FROM User" which only lets the first registered user in the database login.

The question i really want to ask is something like this: fetch the column where the username thats being inputed matches with the column.

This is my take on it:

```
 "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '$_post['username_input']'"
```

but i just get error message.

How should i ask this question? thanks for the help in advance!

```
<form method='post'>
    <table>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' name='username_input' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type='text' name='password_input' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Logga in' /></td></tr>
    </table>
<form>

<?php
    $link = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
    $sql_result = $link->query ("SELECT * FROM User");
    $rad = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql_result); 

    $columnuser = $rad['username'];
    $columnpassword = $rad['password'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if ($_POST['username_input'] == $columnuser && md5 ($_POST['password_input']) == $columnpassword) {
            $_SESSION['log_in'] = true;
            header("Location: administration.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Fel användarnamn eller lösenord, vänligen försök igen.";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close ($link);
?>
```

Comment: try `"SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '".$_post['username_input']."'"`

Comment: Also u are vulnerable to SQL Injection so shift to PDO prepare statement.

Comment: You need to learn about `WHERE` clauses and [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: -infinity points for `u`. Stop being lazy and type the damn word out properly. This is not myspace/dramabook/twitter.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: i get this error Notice: Undefined variable: _post in /home/almu0004/public_html/loggain.php on line 15

Comment: As Marc B said. Also it is a query (you are querying the database) and not a question (asking the database). It is not a phpmyadmin database, it is a MySQL database. phpmyadmin is a tool to access a graphic view of MySQL.

Comment: $_post should be $_POST

Comment: After i changed it to $_POST i get this error instead Notice: Undefined index: username_input in /home/almu0004/public_html/loggain.php on line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am thinking you are making mistake in query is concatenation of variable and $_POST is array which is capitalized

```
"SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '".$_POST['username_input']."' "
```

I hope this solves your problem.

**Edit:** The error you might be getting because code runs always, you should have condition in starting as

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {    
        $link = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx");
        $sql_result = $link->query ("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '".$_POST['username_input']."' ");
        $rad = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql_result); 

        $columnuser = $rad['username'];
        $columnpassword = $rad['password'];


        if ($_POST['username_input'] == $columnuser && md5 ($_POST['password_input']) == $columnpassword) {
             $_SESSION['log_in'] = true;
             header("Location: administration.php");
        }
        else {
            echo "Fel användarnamn eller lösenord, vänligen försök igen.";
        }
        mysqli_close ($link);
    }
?>
```

Comment: It gives me this error instead, Notice: Undefined index: username_input in /home/almu0004/public_html/loggain.php on line 15

Comment: Thanks alot mate it worked, this is what i tryed to do before but i did something wrong =/.

Answer (score 0):

This is how usually i do :

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = "'.$_post['username_input'].'"
```

I hope i answered the question ... Peace

Comment: I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$_post['' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home/almu0004/public_html/loggain.php on line 15

Answer (score 0):

You have two options how to get rid of an error:

```
$sql_result = $link->query ("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = '$_POST[username_input]'");
```

OR

```
$sql_result = $link->query ("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ".$_POST['username_input']);
```

I'd suggest you to use string escape functions, otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL-injections.
In mysqli you can use "prepare" statements, then your code will be like this:

```
$sql_result = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ?");
$sql_result = $sql_result->bind_param("s", $_POST['username_input']);
$sql_result->execute();
```

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Also POST query does not exist always, so you need to check it, otherwise there will be an error when you try to make a query with non-existing key.
It will be something like that:

```
if(array_key_exists('username_input', $_POST)){
//search for a user in database
}
```